# Eclipse/Android Logcat: open file + go to line from the stack trace

Tags: android, eclipse

While debugging with Logcat I'd like be able to open files/scroll to a line  by clicking at  the line numbers in the stack trace - is there any plugin or option that enables this functionality ?

UPD:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Thanks

Comment: I think its works normal with the eclipse IDE (in linux), I have it working with out any extra plugins

Comment: same here but it doesn't work - I'm using the latest adt plugin with indigo eclipse(linux edition)

Comment: It's the default. It should work unless you're trying to view a Class you don't have the source to.